# Can you upgrade a virtualenv while in venv?

Tags: 14.04

I was in venv in Ubuntu 14.04, and before I thought it over, I used the `sudo apt-get upgrade` command while in venv. Now I want to know if it is a true upgrade of my virtualenv or not and do I need to fix it?

Comment: You mean `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: This depends on whether you have created the virtualenv using the `--system-site-packages` option.

Answer (score 2):

A Python Virtual Environment ("venv") does not affect applications unrelated to Python.

It only adds the `bin/` directory of the venv which contains its executables to the front of your `PATH` variable. This causes a command look-up for e.g. `python` to resolve to that instead of the system's executable. Additionally it changes some other environment variables and aliases used by Python.

None of these changes should break `apt-get` and it's impossible that they affect the way how system packages are managed.

To conclude, it is safe to run `apt-get` or similar stuff while operating in a Python Virtual Environment.

If you want, you can examine the `bin/activate` script in your venv's directory which you use to enter the virtual environment. That way you can see exactly what gets changed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes only if you have created the virtualenv using the `--system-site-packages` option.

Running `sudo apt-get upgrade` upgrades system Python packages (prefixed with `python-` for Python 2 packages and `python3-` for Python 3 packages) that you have previously installed using `apt-get`. If your virtualenv is created using the `--system-site-packages` option, then it uses the system Python packages and does not have its own site packages. In this case, `sudo apt-get upgrade` upgrades your virtualenv in the sense that the system Python packages it uses are upgraded.